# Retrieving a list of my apps on playstore

Tags: java, android, google-play

I've come across many apps that provide a "More Apps" option that shows a list of apps made by the same developer and if you clicked one of them it takes you to the app on PlayStore, what is the best way to do this ?
PS:I don't have a Website

Comment: Probably would be as simple as opening a package that shows all apps under a certain developer name.

Comment: What you mean by package and where do the application will get it from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Link to a Product List in a web view within your app**

You can trigger an intent in your app with

```
http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:publisher_name
```

to open up in the browser and replace publisher_name with yours.

Or

```
market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>
```

to open play store app

The product list lets users see all of the apps from a specific publisher, with ratings, editorial badges, and an Install button for each.

More options at: https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html